# pgbouncer windows 10 - client_login_timeout(server_down) error

Tags: postgresql, pgbouncer

I am trying to setup pgbouncer on my local machine. I have standard (didnt change anything after installation) configuration file with entries:

`postgres = host=127.0.0.1 port=5432
listen_addr = *
listen_port = 6432
auth_type = trust //also tested with md5 and plain`

My postgresql (ver 9.4) is running on port 5432. When I execute

`psql -U postgres -p 5432 -d postgres`

i can successfully connect. Now i am trying to connect to pgbouncer

`psql -U postgres -p 6432 -d postgres`

after providing password pgbouncer cannot connect (it hangs for 60 sec) and then timeouts with error

`psql: ERROR: client_login_timeout (server down)`

Pgbouncer logs:

`2017-05-05 00:17:27.084 14696 LOG File descriptor limit: -1 (H:-1), max_client_conn: 100, max fds possible: 130
2017-05-05 00:17:27.104 14696 LOG listening on ::/6432
2017-05-05 00:17:27.105 14696 LOG listening on 0.0.0.0:6432
2017-05-05 00:17:27.106 14696 LOG process up: pgbouncer 1.7.2, libevent 2.0.21-stable (win32), adns: evdns2, tls: OpenSSL 1.0.2k  26 Jan 2017
2017-05-05 00:18:27.104 14696 LOG Stats: 0 req/s, in 0 b/s, out 0 b/s,query 0 us
2017-05-05 00:18:51.852 14696 LOG C-009B8FE0: postgres/postgres@[::1]:55878 login attempt: db=postgres user=postgres tls=no
2017-05-05 00:18:51.854 14696 WARNING 
2017-05-05 00:18:51.854 14696 LOG S-009EF248: postgres/postgres@127.0.0.1:5432 closing because: connect failed (age=0)
2017-05-05 00:19:06.929 14696 WARNING 
2017-05-05 00:19:06.929 14696 LOG S-009EF248: postgres/postgres@127.0.0.1:5432 closing because: connect failed (age=0)
2017-05-05 00:19:21.949 14696 WARNING 
2017-05-05 00:19:21.950 14696 LOG S-009EF248: postgres/postgres@127.0.0.1:5432 closing because: connect failed (age=0)
2017-05-05 00:19:27.105 14696 LOG Stats: 0 req/s, in 0 b/s, out 0 b/s,query 0 us
2017-05-05 00:19:36.969 14696 WARNING 
2017-05-05 00:19:36.970 14696 LOG S-009EF248: postgres/postgres@127.0.0.1:5432 closing because: connect failed (age=0)
2017-05-05 00:19:51.990 14696 LOG C-009B8FE0: postgres/postgres@[::1]:55878 closing because: client_login_timeout (server down) (age=60)
2017-05-05 00:19:51.991 14696 WARNING C-009B8FE0: postgres/postgres@[::1]:55878 Pooler Error: client_login_timeout (server down)
2017-05-05 00:20:27.105 14696 LOG Stats: 0 req/s, in 0 b/s, out 0 b/s,query 0 us`

hba.conf 

`host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5`

postgresql.conf

`listen_addresses = '*'`

What I am doing wrong?

## `EDIT 1:`

Struggling to make this work I tried:

1. Connecting to other db versions: 9.5 and 9.6
2. Since I saw in logs that various ports are used I opened whole pgbouncer app in firewall, before that I opened only 6432 port
3. I thought maybe pgbouncer has problems connecting to localhost so I tried to connect to remote server
4. Even disabled antivirus

None of above worked. Always the same log shows up (port 5434 is 9.5 version):

```
2017-05-05 22:26:01.899 8008 LOG C-010C8FF0: postgres/postgres@[::1]:61687 login attempt: db=postgres user=postgres tls=no
2017-05-05 22:26:01.899 8008 LOG C-010C8FF0: postgres/postgres@[::1]:61687 closing because: client unexpected eof (age=0)
2017-05-05 22:26:04.753 8008 LOG C-010C8FF0: postgres/postgres@[::1]:61690 login attempt: db=postgres user=postgres tls=no
2017-05-05 22:26:04.753 8008 WARNING 
2017-05-05 22:26:04.753 8008 LOG S-010FF258: postgres/postgres@127.0.0.1:5434 closing because: connect failed (age=0)
2017-05-05 22:26:19.803 8008 WARNING 
2017-05-05 22:26:19.803 8008 LOG S-010FF258: postgres/postgres@127.0.0.1:5434 closing because: connect failed (age=0)
2017-05-05 22:26:35.086 8008 WARNING 
2017-05-05 22:26:35.086 8008 LOG S-010FF258: postgres/postgres@127.0.0.1:5434 closing because: connect failed (age=0)
2017-05-05 22:26:41.581 8008 LOG Stats: 0 req/s, in 0 b/s, out 0 b/s,query 0 us
2017-05-05 22:26:50.359 8008 WARNING 
2017-05-05 22:26:50.359 8008 LOG S-010FF258: postgres/postgres@127.0.0.1:5434 closing because: connect failed (age=0)
2017-05-05 22:27:04.961 8008 LOG C-010C8FF0: postgres/postgres@[::1]:61690 closing because: client_login_timeout (server down) (age=60)
2017-05-05 22:27:04.961 8008 WARNING C-010C8FF0: postgres/postgres@[::1]:61690 Pooler Error: client_login_timeout (server down)
```

Can someone explain why it tries to connect on port 61687? On this port it gets unexpected eof.

Here is the whole pgbouncer.ini (lines that are not commented out):

```
[databases]
postgres = host=127.0.0.1 port=5434 dbname=postgres
[pgbouncer]
logfile = C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\PgBouncer\log\pgbouncer.log
pidfile = C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\PgBouncer\log\pgbouncer.pid
listen_addr = *
listen_port = 6432
auth_type = md5
auth_file = C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\PgBouncer\etc\userlist.txt
admin_users = postgres
stats_users = postgres
pool_mode = session
max_client_conn = 100
default_pool_size = 20
```

Comment: Are you sure your postgresql server is receiving connections on localhost? Try `psql -h 127.0.0.1 ...` and just confirm you can connect.

Comment: Yes, it is working. I can connect `psql -U postgres -h 127.0.0.1 -p 5432 -d postgres`

Comment: OK, now for pgbouncer set `auth_type = md5` and check your `auth_file` contains the right username/password pairing. Then try again connecting through pgbouncer. First use the *wrong* password, then the right one. See what is logged.

Comment: Then, assuming you can connect to pgbouncer itself, check the settings in your `[databases]` section for what user/password you are using there.

Comment: After providing wrong password i got `Auth failed` and after correct password `client_login_timout`. I do not set any password in databases settings.but even if i do `postgres = host=127.0.0.1 port=5432 user=postgres password=pass` still not help. I thought maybe pgbouncer uses different host during connection (like hostname) so i edited hba.conf `host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0            md5` also without help.

Comment: I'm stumped. I've never had a problem once I knew I could connect and had the user/password settings correct.

Comment: @patryks I'm running in the same issue, any chance you solved this?

Comment: @Francescu Unfortunately, no.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was an issue of Port number in the [Database] section.
The default (if not set) is 5432.
On my machine, Ubuntu 22 and PostgreSQL 15 the port is **5433**.
I set it explicitly in the [Database] section, now it works perfectly.